# ASP.NET C# MVC - Change format for datetime directly on DB or Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime

I'm struggling myself trying to find an easy way to change the DateTime format for my Table field.

I have a Model called Article with a field called releaseDate that is a DateTime

I managed to do it (visually) by converting the

```
Article.releaseDate.ToString("dd/MM/yy")
```

but the thing is when I try to submit a date with this format from the create action it returns an error telling the the format is wrong.

Any easy way to change the default **("MM/dd/yy")** to **("dd/MM/yy")**?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could change the culture information on a page by page basis by including

```
<%@ Page UICulture="en" Culture="en-GB" %>
```

or globally across all pages by adding to your web.config

```
<globalization uiCulture="en" culture="en-GB" />
```

Both will change the DateTime model binding to dd/MM/yyyy so no conversion is necessary.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124956/how-do-i-change-the-default-input-format-on-the-datetime-model-binder-in-net-mvc/1125022#1125022) for more information

The code equivalent is

```
CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat
 = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat
 = new CultureInfo( "en-GB", false ).DateTimeFormat;
```

Comment: Thanks a Lot Dave web.config solution solved my problem quickly

Answer (score 3):

Yep. It sure is mate :)

try changing the current thread's CULTURE. By default, it takes the system's OS. but u can override that.

check this out...

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
```

[Here's a good post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/EnablingEvilOverridingSystemDateTimesDefaultToString.aspx) explaining ....

HTH.

Comment: Thanks for you answer Pure.Krome, As I was looking to change all the app defaults maybe the web.config solution from Dave seemed to be the straight forward one.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here is that since the compiler only sees `two digits/two digits/two digits` in both cases, it has no way to know that you want `day/month/year` instead of `month/day/year` until it tries to actually casts, and notices that your value for the month is `>= 12`.

You could solve this by splitting the date on `/`, and throwing in the arguments in the "correct" order to the compiler, like so:

```
string[] dateParts = input.Split("/");
int day; int month; int year;

// You could use a boolean variable here to double-check that all casts are successful
Int32.TryParse(dateParts[0], out day);
Int32.TryParse(dateParts[1], out month);
Int32.TryParse(dateParts[2], out year);

var output = new DateTime(year, month, day);
```

If you put this in a separate function you could use it like this to support both formats:

```
DateTime releaseDate;
try
{
    // will throw exception if input is not in the default format
    releaseDate = new DateTime(input);
}
catch (InvalidFormatException ex)
{
    releaseDate = GetDateTimeFromNonStandardInput(input);
}
catch 
{
    throw; // or do whatever error handling you feel like.
}
```

Personally, I'd write the `GetDateTimeFromNonStandardInput()` as an extension method to the `DateTime` class.