# asp mvc EditorFor DateTime not displaying

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to display a datetime field retrieved froma  database in my razor file with the following:

```
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RequestDate);
```

I know with 100% certainty the RequestDate is not null, as I examined the model that was passed in the view, and it was the date from the database. However, the datetime textbox still displays "mm/dd/yyyy". I don't know why it is not display the date. Any ideas? Thank you.

Here is my model:

```
      [Display(Name = "Time")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime RequestDate { get; set; }
```

**EDIT:**

```
   [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult DispatchResponseIndex()
    {
        DispatchResponseModel model = new DispatchResponseModel();       


        //if the users session id isnt null then we know they have data related to this form
        object UserID = Session["TestID"];
        if (UserID == null)
        {
            return View(model); //default view               
        }
        else
        {
            UserID = Session["TestID"];
        }

        LoadDB(model, (Guid)UserID);
     //looking at the model here the RequestDate has a valid date of  //{5/24/2013 12:00:00 AM}

        return View(model); 
    }
```

**EDIT 2:**

If I use  @Html.TextBox("asdasd",Model.RequestDate); Then it will display the saved date in string format, but I need to use the built in date editor for the text box.

Comment: add your action to see what's happening

Comment: Could you elaborate a little? I have been using MVC for a week. I set the RequestDate in my controller and passed it into the view. Is this not enough?

Comment: it should be enough but, check in your model you have and what annotation you added it could be something with the DisplayFormat

Comment: Ah I think it may be because its a date and not a datetime/

Comment: Can you show us how you're passing the model to your View? Just to rule out any errors there

Comment: Alrght, I added the changes.

Comment: Have you seen this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5252979/assign-format-of-datetime-with-data-annotations ?

Comment: @JohnEdwards Change to to @Html.EditorFor!

Comment: Have you changed or created your own Editor Template? That may have something to do with it

Comment: I have editor templates not related to this. They are custom ones and dont modify EditorFor or TextBox or anything like that.

Comment: I ask because if `TextBox()` works, but `EditorFor` doesnt I was wondering if there was a custom EditorFor. it would be `~\Views\Shared\EditorTemplates\DateTime.cshtml`

Comment: Why are you specifying the DataType when your property is already of type DateTime? I would start by removing [DataType(DataType.Date)]...

Comment: If I remove [DataType(DataType.Date)], then the built in textbox date dropper no longer works.

Comment: What do you mean by built in? There is no built in as far as I know, you need to use JQuery datepicker...

Comment: Yea I am a dummy. Apparently Chrome has a built in one and I thought it was MVC. Sorry:(

Answer (score 28):

This does seem to cause a lot of confusion and it annoyed me!

If you use `DataType.Date` you need to set it like this:

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
```

[Chrome's date picker uses the local computer's short date format.](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2012/08/Quick-FAQs-on-input-type-date-in-Google-Chrome)  Even setting the `lang` tag is ignored; here is an example using Chrome and `<html lang="en-GB">`:

[image]

Chrome's date picker also uses the local computer's locale.  On page load, the date will be populated (if set) and the user can select a new date:

[image]

**Note:** If you change the computer's locale you must restart Chrome completely to see the locale change.

Comment: Sadly, this solution also affects DisplayFor(), so all your dates will display in this international format.

Answer (score 16):

**FINAL**

I'm an idiot. I had no idea Chrome had a date picker that it added. I thought it was something built into MVC. I need to use an actual jquery date picker. Thanks everyone for all the info.

Comment: You're not the only one, just happened to me and this comment helped me realize it.

Comment: Its HTML5 Datepicker which each HTML5 browser implements its self. Differently for Mobile and Desktop too, so its native to the platform and set the the locale properly. It took me a while to work out what was going on with this too. But once you know, your the boss.

Answer (score 3):

Add Format line in you model

```
[Display(Name = "Time")]        
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime RequestDate { get; set; }
```

**Update**

OR

Can you change the model property datetime to string. and convert your datetime object to string !!

OR

Or you can format that value in your editor field .for sample like

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FromDate, "{0:d}")
```

Comment: I tried this, and it still just displays "mm/dd/yyyy".It is getting very peculiar. I am using [DataType(DataType.Date)] so I can have the built in date editor.

Comment: Can you change the model property datetime to string. and convert your datetime object to string !!

Comment: So you want me to say "public String RequestDate { get; set; }"?Because that removes the date editor.

Comment: Yes . Or you can format that value in your editor field .for sample like

@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FromDate, "{0:d}")

Comment: Hm, I tried   @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.RequestDate, "{0:d}"
and it displays a date, but there is no longer any date dropdown for that text box.

Comment: Hey that's a sample format. Now you use this {0:MM/dd/yyyy} instead of {0:d}

Comment: @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.RequestDate, "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")                                              
     Still doesn't display the date picker:(

Comment: See this blog.  It's explain more detail's

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stuartleeks/archive/2011/01/25/asp-net-mvc-3-integrating-with-the-jquery-ui-date-picker-and-adding-a-jquery-validate-date-range-validator.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Actually until I saw this post, I didn't realise there's "date picker" difference between Chrome and IE, even though I got the sample page layout from the MVC's tutorial.

For someone who doesn't realise the difference, as I did before, please find below the comparison:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

DataFormatString MUST be EXACT like this "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}" then and only then @Html.EditorFor works with date picker control.

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact same problem. If you look at the HTTP Post that was going back to the Controller and the format of the date in the POST it is yyyy-MM-dd.

I changed my data annotation to this and it worked ...    Except now the Index list view shows yyyy-mm-dd format.    And the Edit shows mm/mm/yyyy in a datepicker control?

Added to Model Date -

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")
```

IMHO EVERY app I've seen since 1980 has used dates and times.    Why is this still a mess Mr MS?

Answer (score 1):

This is how i do it inside the model

```
[Display(Name = "Effective Date")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}")]
    public DateTime? Effectivedate 
    {
        get { return EffectivedateEdit; }
        set { EffectivedateEdit = value; EffectivedateEdit = value; } 
    }


    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
    public DateTime? EffectivedateEdit { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

> It also take me about 5days to find out how make it done, so may be help someome

> first in Model you should have line : **[DataType(DataType.Date)]**

> Then in View, you shoud user    @Html.TextBoxFor  instead of  @Html.EditorFor

```
enter 

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime Expireddate { get; set; }
```

code here

> inview as below:

```
enter  <td>

                  
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.Expireddate.Date, "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}",

                  new
                  {
                      onkeydown = "return  event.keyCode != 13",
                      @class = "form-control datepicker",
                      @type = "date",
                      @value = ToolShare.datetoStringyyyymmddviewnet(@item.Expireddate.Date),
                      id = @item.id,
                      onChange = "replaceContentsOfDivupdateExpireddate(this.id, this.value)"

                  })


                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(modelItem => item.Expireddate)
                </td>
```

code here

> function  datetoStringyyyymmddviewnet to convert datetime to string like : yyyy-mm-dd

```
enter  public static String datetoStringyyyymmddviewnet(DateTime datevalue)
    {

        // yyyy-mm-dd  to date

       

        return datevalue.Year +"-" + datevalue.Month +"-"+ datevalue.Day;
    }
```

code here