# Putting date format on ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, datetime

I am working on a library management website. I have some troubles setting the date in ASP.NET.

How can I let the application user choose the current dateformat when they are creating an item?

**Create.csshtml**

```
   @model LibraryProject.LibraryItem

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>


    @using (Html.BeginForm()) 
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        
        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <h4>Book</h4>
            <hr />
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    
    
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CategoryId, "Category", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.DropDownList("CategoryId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CategoryId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
    
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
    
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Author, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Author, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Author, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
    
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Pages, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Pages, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Pages, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
    
           
    
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsBorrowable, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.IsBorrowable)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IsBorrowable, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Borrower, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Borrower, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Borrower, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
    
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BorrowDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BorrowDate, "The date is created automatically.", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
    
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Type, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Type, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Type, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
    
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
    
    <div>
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
    </div>
    
    @section Scripts {
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    }
```

[image]

So as you can see on the image, when the user creates a book, I want to get the borrowdate, what is the best way of doing that?

Comment: Use an `input` control with `type='date'`.

Comment: Could you give me code example please? @JamshaidKamran

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23397980/4308286

Comment: One way of doing so is just putting it in the controller action, instantiate the new object, set all of the fields to the form values, then set Borrowdate to DateTime.Now,