# Changing date format in ASP.NET MVC C#

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How can I change the date format for asp.net model view control?

Can any one help me out?

Is there any chance to change the date format with out creating a new class

```
public class Story
{
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The Title is required")]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime? PostDate { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The Text is required")]
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public virtual string Image { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply a [data annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5252979/assign-format-of-datetime-with-data-annotations) to the field.  For example if you want UK format:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime? PostDate { get; set; }
```

This will be reflected in the display and edit modes if you are using the standard `EditorFor`.

[Edit]

In your cshtml, you can then use:

```
@DisplayFor(model => model.PostDate)
```

Comment: still the same nothing has changed

Comment: Can you include the cshtml where you use the field in your question?

Comment: Or `@TextBoxFor(m => m.PostDate, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")`

Comment: <p>@Model.PostDate.ToString()</p>

Comment: @KhaledAl-sadi, Add the code to your question (not in comments). And you can use `@DisplayFor(m => m.PostDate)` with the `[DisplayFormat(..)]` shown above (or `@Model.PostDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")`. Please click on the help link next time you comment and learn how to format them

Comment: Try `@DisplayFor(model => model.PostDate)`.