# ASP MVC change display date time format

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime, razor

My date is displayed like dd/mm/yyyy. I want it displayed like yyyy-mm-dd.

```
 @Html.EditorFor(x=> x.DateChosen, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "choosetime" } })
```

I already tried

```
  @Html.EditorFor(x=> x.DateChosen, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id =     "choosetime", "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}" } })
```

Comment: Have you looked into data attributes for your model properties?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5252979/assign-format-of-datetime-with-data-annotations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is [DisplayFormatAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayformatattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) :

```
public class MyModel 
{
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime DateChosen { get; set; }

    // Other properties goes there
}
```

And use your Html helper like this :

```
 @Html.EditorFor(x=> x.DateChosen, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "choosetime" } })
```

### Edit 1 :

Base on comment, if you need to access the string representation of the `DateChosen` property somewhere else in your code, you can update your model like that :

```
public class MyModel 
{
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime DateChosen { get; set; }

    public string DateChosenString
    {
        return DateChosen.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
    }     

    // Other properties goes there
}
```

Comment: Just look at my comment @codeislife this is a duplicate

Comment: This work, tested locally, can you update your question with the full code of your model and how you are using your html helper ?

Comment: You should specify ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, because it's that telling the Html helper to apply this format when rendering the textbox.

Comment: Instead of DateTime type, I am using a type String. Can that be the problem?

Comment: It's that. You don't use DateTime for a special reason ?

Comment: Yes. I need it for a string somewhere else in my code. Is there another way? Can I convert it to the yyyy-mm-dd form  there by any chance?@Html.EditorFor(x=> x.DateChosen, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "choosetime" } })

Comment: Thanks so much. Now I am getting that the ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") has invalid arguments.

Comment: Hum, it work perfectly on my machine, Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")) give me 2016-04-15. You can check this overload of the ToString method on MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx.
Can you please paste your model code ?