# Value of datepicker textfield is wrong

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have the following Razor

```
<td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MeetingToEdit.StartTime, new { @class = "datetimepicker form-control", @Value = Model.MeetingToEdit.StartTime })</td>
```

I access the date from the Controller as

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult UpdateMeetingWithId([Bind(Prefix = "MeetingToEdit")]Meeting model)
    {
        Meeting meeting = meetingsContext.Meetings.Where(a => a.Id == model.Id).First();
        meeting.Title = model.Title;
        meeting.StartTime = model.StartTime;
        meeting.EndTime = model.EndTime;
        meetingsContext.Entry(meeting).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
        meetingsContext.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("ReinviteVisitor2", "Home", new { visitorId = model.SubjectId });
    }
```

So when debugging the chtml, Model.MeetingToEdit.StartTime is correct however when it gets displayed in the textbox in the webpage it is wrong and becomes "Jan 14, 0044 12:00 AM". What is the correct way to ensure the datetime is displayed correctly in the textfield?

EDIT:
I am using bootstrap datetimepicker and it is configured as follows:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
        format: 'lll'
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Never set the `value` attribute when using a `HtmlHelper` method. What is the value of `StartTime` and how do you want it formatted? And you have mentioned a DatePicker - what jquery DatePicker are you using?

Comment: OK I took the value attributed off. But now the StartTime and EndTime is empty. I think it is because the format is not correct?

Comment: Again, what is the value of `StartTime` and how do you want to display it?

Comment: StartTime and EndTime are DateTimes and I want it displayed as 'Mon 18 Jul 2016 4:32 PM'

Comment: Then it would be `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MeetingToEdit.StartTime, "{0: ddd dd MMM yyyy h:mm tt}", new { @class = "datetimepicker form-control" })` but you will likely not be able to bind that back to your model when you submit

Comment: still getting empty textfield

Comment: Then the values of you properties are `null` (or you have an error in attaching the plugin but you still have  not shown that)

Comment: sorry it is because I didn't copy across the classes as your example..Now it is displaying ok.

Comment: However the datepicker doesn't work. Seems like if I remove the "datetimepicker" class the textfield is displayed ok otherwise it is empty.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117572/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-rukiman).

Comment: See edits in the question for type of datetimepicker

Answer (score 0):

Explicitly specify the date format, i.e.

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MeetingToEdit.StartTime.ToString("M/d/yyyy"), new { @class = "datetimepicker form-control", @Value = Model.MeetingToEdit.StartTime })

```
`some other formats u can apply like :
```

// month/day numbers without/with leading zeroes
String.Format("{M/d/yyyy}");            // "3/9/2008"
String.Format("{MM/dd/yyyy}");          // "03/09/2008"

// day/month names
String.Format("{ddd, MMM d, yyyy}");    // "Sun, Mar 9, 2008"
String.Format("{dddd, MMMM d, yyyy}");  // "Sunday, March 9, 2008"

// two/four digit year
String.Format("{MM/dd/yy}");            // "03/09/08"
String.Format("{MM/dd/yyyy}");          // "03/09/2008"
`

Comment: I got an InvalidOperationException for this line @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MeetingToEdit.StartTime.ToString("M/d/yyyy"), new { @class = "datetimepicker form-control" })

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5252979/assign-format-of-datetime-with-data-annotations). Basically you have two options. Either set the `DisplayFormat` annotation in your view model to define the date format. In that case you'll need to use the `EditorFor` helper method in your view instead of `TextBoxFor`.

The second option is to pass the date format into the `TextBoxFor` helper method. There are examples in the providede link.