# Validation with Timepicker not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, time

I have a form made with MVC, using Data Annotations and timepicker to enter an hour. The validation of the time don´t work, when sending the data it says "The field Hour should be a date", how to solve it? If I change something, the timepicker is not cleared

Controller:

```
namespace TimePicker.Controllers
    {
        public class HomeController : Controller
        {
            // GET: Home
            public ActionResult Index()
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
```

}

Model:

```
namespace TimePicker.Models
{
    public class Hora
    {
        [Required]
        public string Name{ get; set; }
        [Required]
        public TimeSpan Hour { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Hour.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input.timepicker').timepicker({
        timeFormat: 'h:mm p',
        interval: 60,
        minTime: '10',
        maxTime: '6:00pm',
        defaultTime: '11',
        startTime: '10:00',
        dynamic: false,
        dropdown: true,
        scrollbar: true
    });
});
```

View:

```
@model TimePicker.Models.Hour

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Hour</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Hour, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Horario, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Horario, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>

Layout:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    <link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                @Html.ActionLink("Application name", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
        </footer>
    </div>
```

```
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>

<link href="~/Content/jquery.timepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.timepicker.js"></script>

<script src="~/Scripts/Hour.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to Use DataType Data Annotation which is in System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations namespace.Below is the Code.

Otherwise with the use of Regular Expressions can do the best for this.Below is the link

[Assign format of DateTime with data annotations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5252979/assign-format-of-datetime-with-data-annotations)

```
namespace TimePicker.Models
{
    public class Hora
    {
        [Required]
        public string Name{ get; set; }
        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Time,ErrorMessage="Your Message")]
        [RegularExpression(@"^(0[1-9]|1[0-2]):[0-5][0-9] (am|pm|AM|PM)$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Time.")]
        public TimeSpan Hour { get; set; }
    }
}
```